Unable To Fetch User Context : from firebase authorizer (lambda func) to the main lambda function
Problem:
I have a Lambda function acting as a custom authorizer for API Gateway, which uses Firebase authentication. Despite correctly passing a Firebase ID token in the Authorization header of the request, the response always returns "Not Authorized".
I’m trying to authenticate requests through API Gateway → Lambda (custom authorizer) → Lambda (main handler) but the request fails authentication, even when the token is valid and correct.
What I’ve Tried:

I’ve configured a custom authorizer Lambda function, which validates the Firebase token using Google’s public keys.
I’ve tested the function using Postman, sending the Firebase token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.
I’ve tried different API Gateway configurations (HTTP API vs. REST API), but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Here’s the code for the Lambda custom authorizer function:
**here is my firebase authorizer function **
import json
import time
import urllib.request
from typing import Dict, Any
import jwt
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def lambda_handler(event: Dict[str, Any], context: Any) -> Dict:
    try:
        # Get token from header
        auth_header = event.get('headers', {}).get('authorization', '')
        if not auth_header or not auth_header.lower().startswith('bearer '):
            print("No valid Authorization header")
            return {'isAuthorized': False}
        
        token = auth_header.split(' ')[1]
        
        # Get Google's public keys
        google_keys_url = 'xxxxx'
        req = urllib.request.Request(
            google_keys_url,
            headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
        )
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        public_keys = json.loads(response.read())
        
        # Get key ID from token header
        header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
        key_id = header.get('kid')
        
        if not key_id or key_id not in public_keys:
            print(f"Invalid key ID: {key_id}")
            print(f"Available keys: {list(public_keys.keys())}")
            return {'isAuthorized': False}
        
        # Load the certificate and extract the public key
        cert_str = public_keys[key_id]
        cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert_str.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())
        public_key = cert_obj.public_key()
        
        # Verify token
        decoded = jwt.decode(
            token,
            public_key,
            algorithms=['RS256'],
            audience='xxxx',  #  Firebase project ID
            issuer='xxxxx',  #  Firebase project ID
            options={
                'verify_exp': True,
                'verify_iss': True,
                'verify_aud': True
            }
        )
        
        # Token is valid
        return {
            'isAuthorized': True,
            'context': {
                'userId': str(decoded.get('user_id') or decoded.get('sub')),
                'email': str(decoded.get('email')),
                'emailVerified': str(decoded.get('email_verified', False)),
                'projectId': 'fillsapp'
            }

        }
        
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError as e:
        print(f"Invalid token error: {str(e)}")
        return {'isAuthorized': False}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return {'isAuthorized': False}


main function
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        logger.info(f"Received event: {safe_json_dumps(event)}")
        
        cors_headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE'
        }
        
        if event.get('httpMethod') == 'OPTIONS':
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'headers': cors_headers,
                'body': ''
            }

        # Get user ID from authorizer
        user_id = event.get('requestContext', {}).get('authorizer', {}).get('user')
        
        if not user_id:
            return {
                'statusCode': 401,
                'headers': cors_headers,
                'body': json.dumps({'error': 'Not authorized'})
            }


when i am trying to test through postman -> apigateway -> lambda, it always returns me Not authorized
Questions/Issues:

Are there any common pitfalls in setting up a custom authorizer that might cause the request to be rejected?
Does the Lambda authorizer return the correct user context (e.g., userId, email) back to the main function, and if not, what could cause this?
How do I correctly configure the API Gateway to pass the token to the custom authorizer and then to the main function?

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on resolving the issue where the Lambda always returns "Not authorized" even though the token is valid.

**# Tried through different API Gateway configurations, Still unable to resolve it,
its a HTTP API**
authorizer config settings
